# Add css style for div tag on fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two hidden blocks which I want to show with slightly animation. I'm adding css style with jquery' method **.css**. But it's just probably overriding main style and nothing is happening with animation.

[**Here is fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8r7Lqs46/1/)

Starting css of hidden blocks

```
.da727e, .ac6c82 {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

after I'm changing css with .css method

```
item.css({'display' : 'block', 
          'visibility' : 'visible', 
          'opacity' : '1', 
          'transition' : 'visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear'});
```

A bit of js&jquery

```
var rectContainer = [
    $(".da727e"),
    $(".ac6c82"),
];

for(var i = 0; i <= rectContainer.length; i++) {
    var item = rectContainer[i],
        container = $("html, body"),
        wrapper = $('.wrapper');

      (function(item) {
            $('.ffbc67').click(function() {
                item.css({'display' : 'block', 'visibility' : 'visible', 'opacity' : '1', 'transition' : 'visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear'});

                wrapper.css({'display' : 'flex', 'visibility' : 'visible', 'height' : '100vh'});

                container.animate({
                    scrollTop: item.offset().top
                }, 250);
            });
  })(item);
}
```

After you will click on first block and the other will appear, try to inspect the last two blocks and with inspect change opacity from 0 > 1 and you will see this slight animation. How can I achieve it, where is the problem?

[**GIF for demonstration**](https://dr5mo5s7lqrtc.cloudfront.net/items/1I2S2j3N2e2o141s1f2k/Screen%20recording%202017-09-25%20at%2003.01.48%20AM.gif?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=2831486&v=9cd34a7c)

Comment: The fiddle showed 3 background colors: yellow, light purple and dark purple, it was very fast, What exactly did you expect and what are you actually getting?

Comment: added some further explanation, try to change vh to 50% of its height, you will see even without fast  scrolling speed, that it doesn't have animation

Comment: did change in fiddle

Comment: The thing you are trying to achieve is if when the first block is the clicked the other two will reveal? or you want just the block next to it?

Comment: @cygnus Not really sure what you want so take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/omkqbz6e/

Comment: @zer00ne, that's it! Thanks

Comment: @cygnus Did you want an explanation?

Comment: @zer00ne nah, thanks, u already helped! :)

Comment: @cygnus Ok, well you are very welcome, sir, happy coding.

Comment: @zer00ne haha! same goes to you, sir))

Comment: @zer00ne btw, guess that ur keyframes r not working, it’s just taking animation from .css method, I’m from mobile so can’t say precisely

Comment: @cygnus The keyframes are like transitions but with greater control thereby  resulting in smoother animation. If you are using Safari, prefix transitions, and transforms with `-webkit-`, You should try replacing `.css()` with `toggleClass()`, `.removeClass()`, and `.addClass()`. Also, don't use `display:none` or use `visibility` and `opacity` at the same time. there's no 'inbetween' of display property to animate and visibility and opacity are too similar that overlapping may have a negative affect.